# Is it possible to automate sendkeys to multiple text boxes in a webpage at the same time using multithreading?

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, selenium

I'm trying to find a way to send keys to multiple text boxes in a webpage at the same time using multithreading, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible because interaction with text boxes is always made singlethreded and processed by message/event loop where is always processed one message/event at a time.